# Java: Converting a String with letters in it to an integer

Tags: java

Using Java, I have a boolean method that takes a String containing fuel categories like `E85` or `E93`.

I need the method to convert that to a number.

Pseudocode:

```
if (FUEL IS IN CATEGORY "E")
{
    if (fuelType.length == 4 THIS IS E100 && 
        fuelType.length == 3 THIS IS 10-99){
        if (fuel <= 100 && fuel >= 85){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

There are compile time errors everywhere, how do I do I convert `E85` to `85`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is always E## A string with a single E and any number of digits afterwards, then you can just remove E from your string.

Then convert the rest of the string consisting of only digits to an integer and then do the comparison.

Like this:

```
fuelType = fuelType.substring(1);
int fuelTypeAsInteger = Integer.parseInt(fuelType);
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how and why this works? - THANKS, because it worked!! I kept using .substring(1, 4) or 1, 3. I didnt even think I can use a solid int.

Comment: Its quite straight forward. The first line is just taking a part of string starting from index 1. The first index of the string object is 0. The index 0 has E. So we put 1 as the argument to substring. In result substring gives us the part of string excluding the first character.

In the second line we are using a parse method that is parseInt that takes as an argument a string, that must hold only digits for Integer.parseInt to work. Otherwise it will throw parse exception, if it will have some characters in it. It successfully creates the int when it has only digits in our case.

Comment: Thanks @muasif80 !! Totally understand the concept now. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code to see if your going in the right direction.

```
String category = "E56";
if (category.charAt(0) == 'E') {
    int eNumber = Integer.parseInt(category.subString(1));
    //Now you have the number after the E an can do any checks you want.
    // in this case it would be 56
}
```